# Merits/demerits of using duck typed view models with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

What are the benefits/demerits of using duck typed view models with asp.net mvc?

Recently [I've seen an interesting implementation](http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2010/02/10-minute-twitter-search-app-using-duck.html) of a twitter search client, using fluent C# dynamic XML wrapper to pass data from the controller to the view, to wrap XML data.

It seems like a better way to pass data - viewModel.Foo instead of using ViewData["Foo"] or Foo.Bar instead of XElement("Foo").Attribute("Bar").Value in terms of cleaner code - but I assume it will be having performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Benefits - less code (literally) and readability (in cotrast to `ViewData["foo"]` approach).

Drawbacks - you lose strongly typed view model (and that's something i can't live with). Higher dependency on unit tests. And I'm not sure how things like Mvc2 templates/validation can be attached to dynamic view model.

---

In case you are not familiar with view model idea - take a look at [this](http://www.superexpert.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx). It's way much more powerful beast than it seems at first.